# Java JList not responding correctly after adding new item

Tags: java

I have a problem using JList and I need your help! I've been stuck for a day.

- This is my JList:

  ```
  DefaultListModel lm = new DefaultListModel<>();

  // add "a", "b", "c" to lm
  ...

  list = new JList(lm);
  ```
- My initial JList:

  ```
  |a|
  |b|
  |c|
  ```
- If user double-clicks any items, I will create a new item "d" and add it to the JList and update the JList display

  ```
  list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) { 
        if (evt.getClickCount() == 1)
        {
            lm.add(..., ...);
            list = new JList(lm);
        }
  ```
- Now I have my updated JList:

  ```
  |a|
  |b|
  |c|
  |d|
  ```
- The problem is: from now on, when I double-click any item in a, b, c, or d to add a new item (for example, add "e" to the end of the JList), nothing happens. My JList does not respond anymore.

  ```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
  at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
  at mainprocess.Main$4.valueChanged(Main.java:376)
  at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(Unknown Source)
  at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
  at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
  at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
  at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
  at javax.swing.JList.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
  at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
  at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"     java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
  ```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I can't imagine it's going to end well when you reconstruct the entire value of `list` while *inside an event* attached to that list.  Is there a way just to alter the items contained in the list without remaking a new `JList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not reassign `list` with a `new JList`, just remove that line.

```
  if (evt.getClickCount() == 1)
  {
      lm.add(..., ...);
  }
```